# Fody Stamp taking forever

Tags: git, fody, stamp

simple question here.

I am using Fody Stamp to stamp the current git version to my projects assemblies, and it works perfectly.

My problem is, the solution have a very large number of projects, and each take some time to process making the build take forever every time I want to run it while developing in debug mode. For example, in the log below it took 39.5secs to stamp a single one.

```
27>    Fody: Fody (version 1.29.3.0) Executing
27>      Fody/Stamp:   Starting search for git repository in SolutionDir
27>      Fody/Stamp:   Found git repository in C:\Git\Project\.git\
27>      Fody/Stamp:   Patching version using: C:\Git\Project\Packages\Stamp.Fody.1.2.4\verpatch.exe "C:\Git\Project\Sources\***\obj\Debug\***.dll" /pv "3.24.0-unstable.8+Branch.develop.Sha.20a46c2cf52a0d90128c535af4a8dfb94b4a128c" /high 3.24.0.0
27>      Fody/Stamp:   Waiting 5000 ms while verpatch.exe is processing assembly
27>    Fody:   Finished Fody 39578ms.
```

I'm aware I could just disable the process for the debug build, but I like seeing the unstable version number.

Important point here is, the problem is NOT with the Fody process, but with my computer configuration. How I can see that? Because the exact same project was stamping very fast in the past, and I changed computer (to a faster one), and the problem started. So I'm lead to believe it got to do with how Git is configured on my new computer, but I have no ideas what to look for.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.